# How do I convert a datetime string to a mins ago/day ago/month ago/ year ago format using moment.js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, momentjs

I have a date which is in this format `2020-05-10 22:38:49` coming from my backend API. I'm trying to convert this in `XXX ago` format using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). However, the result is always `a day ago`.

```js
const datetime = moment().utc('2020-05-10 22:38:49').startOf('day').fromNow(); 

console.log(datetime)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-5oApc/wMda1ntIEK4qoWJ4YItnV4fBHMwywunj8gPqc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Could anyone please help?

Comment: For datetime strings that are not ISO 8601 (as yours is), you should provide a [format for parsing](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

Comment: Also, it's `moment.utc()`, not `moment().utc()`. See https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to reference `moment` and call the `.utc()` method - `moment.utc()` - as opposed to `moment().utc()`:

```js
const datetime = moment.utc('2020-05-10 22:38:49').startOf('day').fromNow();

console.log(datetime)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-5oApc/wMda1ntIEK4qoWJ4YItnV4fBHMwywunj8gPqc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: You're right @Phil. Thanks for catching that. I saw a different use of the `.utc()` method in the docs. I updated my answer.